# jQuery Scrolling image animation: Moving in the wrong direction

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm fairly new to jQuery , and I'm trying to scroll and image downwards. The code I'm using is successfully scrolling the image, but sideways, and that's not what I need.

This is the code I'm using

```
$(function(){
    var y = 0;
    setInterval(function(){
        y -= 1;
        $('.scroller').css('background-position', y + 'px 0');
    }, 100);
})
```

If needed, I can provide the CSS and HTML, but those aren't the issue.

Comment: `background-position-y`? BTW, why not using `animate(...,100)` instead of `interval`?

Comment: Just unfamiliar with animate(). Haven't covered that material in my course yet.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because you are changing the X axis... (Read more about [`background-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position) or [*Cartesian coordinate system*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system))

Try this:

```
$('.scroller').css('background-position', '0 ' + y + 'px');
```

Comment: That's exactly what it was. Thank you.